# How to derive covariance between Y and random effect in linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, covariance

In Searle et al.'s book Variance Components, the covariance between the response variable Y and the random effect u is described as follows (highlighted with red rectangle):
[image]

I am not sure why cov(y, u^T) is ZD. I want to see proof of this using expectation calculations beginning with something like cov(y, u^T) = E(y*u^T) - E(y)E(u^T)... or cov(y, u^T) = E[(y - E(y)) (u^T - E(u^T))]. I just do not know how to proceed. Thank you.

---

Fllowing Frank's answer, I also wish to calculate cov(u,y)

cov(u, y) = cov(u, Xβ+Zu+e)
= cov(u, Zu)
= E[uu<sup>T</sup>Z<sup>T</sup>] - E[u]E[u<sup>T</sup>Z<sup>T</sup>] **=E[uu<sup>T</sup>]Z<sup>T</sup>-E[u]E[u<sup>T</sup>]Z<sup>T</sup>** OR **=E[uu<sup>T</sup>]Z<sup>T</sup>-E[u]Z<sup>T</sup>E[u<sup>T</sup>]**

Following the equation before OR, I could proceed and get DZ<sup>T</sup>. However, why is the equation after OR incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since covariance is bilinear and since $X\beta$ is constant and $e$ is independent noise, i.e. independent of $u$, we have:
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{cov}(y, u) &= \operatorname{cov}(X\beta + Zu + e, u)\\
          &= \operatorname{cov}(X\beta, u)+\operatorname{cov}(Zu, u) + \operatorname{cov}(e, u)\\
          &= 0 + \operatorname{cov}(Zu, u) + 0\\
          &= \operatorname{cov}(Zu, u).
\end{align}
$$
Now, by the definition of $\operatorname{cov}$ given by you and, because the expectation is linear, it follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{cov}(y, u) &= \operatorname{cov}(Zu, u)\\
    &= E[Zuu^T] - E[Zu]E[u^T]\\
    &= ZE[uu^T] - ZE[u]E[u^T]\\
    &= Z(E[uu^T] - E[u]E[u^T])\\
    &= Z \operatorname{cov}(u)\\
    &= Z D.\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you. A follow up question is posted as well. BTW, why did the author put cov(y, u^T) rather than cov(y, u) like you did. I am always confused as to when to put this transpose.

Comment: Please don't change questions after they have been answered. This spoils the answer (and the question) for everyone else. Rather, ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will make another post about the new question. Here I have a follow up of the old Q. u is only a q by 1 matrix where q is the number of random covariates in the model. If u is (1 2 3)^T，what is E(u), is it just a number? What about E(uu^T)?

Comment: The expectation of a random vector is a vector. Further, $uu^T$ is a matrix, and the expectation of a random matrix is a matrix.

Comment: A related question has been posted asking about u and u'. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/600559/covariance-between-2-variables-transpose-or-not