# Why is the expectation of a random vector still a vector?

Tags: expected-value, covariance-matrix

In my previous post on [derivation of covariance between y and random effect](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584654/how-to-derive-covariance-between-y-and-random-effect-in-linear-mixed-model), for the following linear model:
[image]

Frank's anwer proved cov(y, u) = ZD as below:
[image]

Frank's proof involved E[u]. As far as I could understand, the random effect variable u in linear mixed model is a vector of 1*q, where q is the number of covariates in the model. My question is why the E[u] is not a single number?

**What I do not understand:
If I have 3 random covariates in the model, then u MUST BE a vector of random variable of size 3*1. An example of u is as follows:**
[image]
then **what is E[u]?** I think u is only a column of numbers, so E[u] should be the average of c(1,2,3), which is 2. However, frank says the expectation of a random vector is still a vector. I know he is right but I do not see why. I want to see the answer E[u] for my example so that I could really see what is E[u], including its dimension and how each number in E[u] is derived.

Comment: You appear to be using two different meanings of "expectation."  At the outset you refer to expectations of *random variables* but midway through you seem to replace that by an operation on a vector of *numbers* consisting of adding its components and dividing by the length.

Comment: oh I think I see your misunderstanding now: you've got in mind that a sample is something we might put in a vector, and so taking the mean of that vector should give us the mean of the sample. But actually people talk about expectations of vectors when each element of their sample is a vector (i.e. three  numbers collected together, like height weight and GPA, and taking the average of the vector is the vector containing the average height, average weight, and average GPA).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that you're overthinking things :). For any vector or matrix of any configuration, its expectation is simply the expectation of each of its elements. If we have:
$$
\mathbf{A} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 \\
x_2 & y_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then to calculate its expectation:

$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{A}] = 
\mathbb{E}\bigg[\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 \\
x_2 & y_2
\end{pmatrix}\bigg] = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{E}[x_1] & \mathbb{E}[y_1] \\
\mathbb{E}[x_2] & \mathbb{E}[y_2]
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So now we see why that the expectation of any vector is going to some other vector of the same shape, because $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}]$ has one element $\mathbb{E}[x_i]$ for each element $x_i$ of $\mathbf{x}$ in the same place.

For your specific question, you ask about $1\times 3$ vectors, but just so you know, the vector you have posted:

$$
\mathbf{u} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

would be denoted in the common notation as a matrix of size $3\times 1$, or would be called a *column vector* of dimension 3.

This is a constant matrix, so its not random, so if we took its expectation we would get the same thing back $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf u]=\mathbf{u}$. But if we had a vector $\mathbf{v}$ with random variables $x_1,x_2,x_3$ in it:

$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{v}] = 
\mathbf{E}\bigg[\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}\bigg] = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{E}[x_1]\\\mathbb{E}[x_2]\\\mathbb{E}[x_3]\end{pmatrix}
$$

we would get an estimate for the population mean of $\mathbf{v}$ (the population mean and sample mean are vectors of the same shape, otherwise the sample mean would make a pretty darn bad estimator!).

Oh, right, also, so far we've been talking about the population quantity: the expectation. You're question title mentions moments but you specifically deal with "sample moments". The sample mean vector is simply the vector of means for each variable:

$$\bar{\mathbf{x}} = \begin{pmatrix}
\bar{x_1} \\ \bar{x_2} \\ \bar{x_3} \end{pmatrix}
$$

You mention covariances too, I couldn't really tell, do you have a question about that or was it just to give background?

Comment: The covariance is just the background from which question on E[u] stems. So am I right to say **cov(u)=E[uu^T]**, since E[u] and E[u^T] are both 0 as required by the mixed model?

Comment: For constants rather than random variable, you mentioned E[u]=u. But how could I write my constant matrix of u in the form of expectation (something like E[u] or E[u^T]) that leads to a single number of 2 rather than being returned a column vector of [1 2 3]^T?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a single number of 2".

Comment: and yes you're right if expectation is zero covariance is expecatation of outer product .

Answer (score 2):

Consider $X \in \mathbb{R}^m$, i.e., $X = \left(\begin{array}{c} X_1 \\ \vdots \\ X_m \end{array}\right)$. Then, we can see that

\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}(X) & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{m}} X f_{X}(X) d X\\
    & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{m}} \left(\begin{array}{c}
       x_1\\
       \vdots \\
       x_m
    \end{array}\right) f_{X}\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right) d x_{1} \ldots d x_{m}\\
    & = \left(\begin{array}{c}
      \int_{\mathbb{R}^{m}} x_1 f_{X}\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right) d x_{1} \ldots d x_{m}\\
      \vdots\\
      \int_{\mathbb{R}^{m}} x_m f_{X}\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right) d x_{1} \ldots d x_{m}
    \end{array}\right)\\
    & = \left(\begin{array}{c}
      \int_{\mathbb{R}} x_1 f_{X_1}\left(x_{1}\right) d x_{1}\\
      \vdots\\
      \int_{\mathbb{R}} x_m f_{X_m}\left(x_{m}\right) d x_{m}
    \end{array}\right)\\
    & = \left(\begin{array}{c}
       \mathbb{E}(X_1)\\
       \vdots\\
       \mathbb{E}(X_m)
    \end{array}\right)
    \end{align*}

---

Notice that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{m}} x_1 f_{X}\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right) d x_{1} \ldots d x_{m} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \dots \int_{\mathbb{R}} x_1 f_{X}\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right) d x_{1} \ldots d x_{m} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x_1 \underbrace{\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \dots \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X}\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}\right) d x_{2} \ldots d x_{m}\right)}_{f_{X_1}\left(x_{1}\right)}d x_{1}$